# ASUS N53SM: Cannot find ram slots

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have had an ASUS N53SM Laptop for four years and wanted to upgrade the amount of memory of it.

As [specs](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/N53SM/specifications/) and `$ sudo lshw -class memory` had said, I expected to have 2 free memory slots on the motherboard. For my surprise, after buying the memory sticks, when I opened the machine I found only two slots, both of them being used.

The motherboard says "SLOT 1, SLOT 2, SLOT 3, SLOT 4" so I'm confused whether they are elsewhere or not.

Are these memory slots in some other place or they simply do not exist?

[image]

Comment: Looks like ASUS used two different versions of the same PCB.  This is common in the business.

Answer (score 1):

More memory slots showing than available is a common thing in laptops. You have only two of them.

I'm not aware of any non-gaming laptops with more than two RAM slots. Some models have just one or have their RAM modules soldered directly to motherboard, which makes them impossible to upgrade.